# Reading text files by path containing asterisk symbol

Tags: c#, .net

I need to read all files that fits `C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyApp\*\*core.*` path. How to do that? Is there any library in .NET to handle this scenario? Something like :

```
string[] allPaths = GetAllPaths("C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyApp\*\*core.*");
var result = new List<string>();

foreach (var path in allPaths)
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {   
        result.Add(line);
    }
}

return result; // Here we go
```

How to do it?

Comment: Windows wildcards cannot tackle that, you'll have to use Regex to filter the results you get from *.*

Answer (score 2):

You could consider

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(
    @"C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyApp",
    "*core.*",
    SearchOption.AllDirectories
);
```

But be aware that `*/?`-patterns could bring unexpected results. See **Notes** at the end of [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

This overload of the Directory.GetFiles method will probably get you want you want.

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

searchPattern can be a combination of literal and wildcard characters, but doesn't support regular expressions. The following wildcard specifiers are permitted in searchPattern.

Wildcard specifiers are * (asterisk) which matches zero or more characters (? (question mark) matches zero or one character).

So you could use "C:\Workspace\MyProject\MyApp\", "*\*core.*" and SearchOption.AllDirectories.